# JMeter Assertion to verify the count of records inserted into database

Tags: jmeter, assertion

**What I am trying to achieve:**

Insert records into Database and verify that the count of records inserted matches with the expected count.

**Steps performed:**

- I have inserted 1 record into a database using a HTTP Request(API).
- I have included a JDBC Request to return the count of records inserted in the database and stored the count * as RESULT
- I have added the variable name in JDBC request as RESULT
- I have created a response assertion in JDBC request and passed the 'JMeter Variable Name to use' as RESULT
- Selected the 'field to test' as 'Text Response'
- 'Pattern Matching Rules' as 'Equal'
- 'Patterns to Test' as '{Result=1}'
- Executed the script

**Assertion Result:**

Assertion error: false
Assertion failure : true
Assertion failure message: Test failed: variable(RESULT)expected to equal/

*******received : [[[[{RESULT=1}]]]]
*******comparison: [[[{RESULT=1}  ]]]

If this issue is resolved, I want to increment the count. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

When using the JDBC Requests, your variables are returned like this: RESULT_1, RESULT_2 and so on..so your variable is actually RESULT_1. So the short answer would be like this:

In the Response Assertion you have to do the following:

1. 'JMeter Variable' as RESULT_1
2. Select the 'field to test' as 'Text Response'
3. 'Pattern Matching Rules' as 'Equals'
4. 'Patterns to Test' as '1'
5. Execute the script

[image]

Comment: heists : Thanks for the response. I have put the below query in JDBC Request

select count(*) FROM Customer WHERE emailAddress ='loadtest.mk@gmail.com';

I have configured the result variable name as 'RESULT_1'
Followed your instructions for Response assertion.,.

Result: JDBC Request - Response Data was count(*) 1

Response Assertion result: 
Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Test failed: variable(RESULT_1) expected to equal /

****** received  : [[[[{count(*)=1}]]]]

****** comparison: [[[1             ]]]

/

Comment: - JDBC Request : https://imgur.com/FkMqeXT 

Response assertion : https://imgur.com/P4yD3uP 

View results Tree: https://imgur.com/4Jy4DDA

Comment: Your response assertion is corect now and should remain intact. The JDBC Request is incorect. You should have kept the variable name as it was before: "RESULT". And you should put it in the "Variable Names" not the "Result Variable Name" area. So, keep the assertion as it is now, modify the jdbc request as I said and you should be good to go.

Comment: heists..  I have inserted 3 records and verified against 1, the response assertion failed. However, when the assertion count matched against the actual #of records inserted, response assertion was not executed. I hope this is the expected behaviour. Thanks a lot for the help. I have attached the images for your reference. https://imgur.com/IWd3vWR

Comment: That's great! Yes indeed the response assertion only shows in the Results Tree if there are problems with the request. So yea, it is expected behaviour. I am glad I could help you. If you are satisfied with the answer, please chose my response as best and upvote it/them. Have a great day!